# Cloud I access builds directory from Jenkins/Hudson?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, clover

I use Jenkins to run Clover, I can see the HTML report on Jenkins' web GUI, but I also want to download clover.pdf. It's created under workspace directory (only newest version) and builds directory like Jenkins\jobs\Job_test\builds\2013-02-19_17-12-25.

Is there any solution to access Jenkins\jobs\Job_test\builds\2013-02-19_17-12-25 from web ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archive the artifact that you require. All the archived artifacts will be stored in Jenkins server and can be accessed from web.

The link to the artifact will look like below
/jenkins/view/Test/job/jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/path/to/mypdf.pdf

This can be achieved though the post build step "archive the artifacts":

[image]